# How to show validation message patchEntity

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP3, I created de Config model with this table :

```
+----------------------+---------------------------+
| param                | value                     |
+----------------------+---------------------------+
| dhcp_dns1            | 192.168.1.100             |
| dhcp_dns2            | 192.168.1.100             |
| dhcp_enabled         | 1                         |
| dhcp_end_ip          | 192.168.1.200             |
| dhcp_netmask         | 255.255.255.0             |
| dhcp_router          | 192.168.1.100             |
| dhcp_start_ip        | 192.168.1.100             |
| host_name            | box                       |
```

I am using a pairs of param/value. param will not be alterable but only value will be alterable.
I have different kind of value (ip address, text, numeric) that I need to validate before change.
So the controller use multi-step save data, to validate different kind of values.

I created a Form (for test) to update host_name (alphaNumeric Validation) and dhcp_start_ip (ipv4 Validation).

For validation I used this :
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#using-a-different-validation-set

Validation works fine but it not display message if validation not match. How I can show message to say Hostname or IP address is wrong format when patchEntity ?
Maybe I am in the wrong way to do it...

This is the view :

```
<div class="config form large-10 medium-9 columns">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('DHCP Config')?></legend>
    <?= $this->Form->create('config') ?>
        <?php

        //$params = array('host_name', 'host_ip', 'host_netmask', 'host_gateway', 'host_dns1', 'host_dns2');
            echo $this->Form->input('host_name',[
                'label' => __('Hostname : '),
                'default' => $host_name->value
            ]);
            echo $this->Form->input('dhcp_start_ip',[
                'label' => __('DHCP Pool start : '),
                'default' => $dhcp_start_ip->value
            ]);
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
public function test()
{
    $host_name = $this->Config->get('host_name', ['contain' => []]);
    $dhcp_start_ip = $this->Config->get('dhcp_start_ip', ['contain' => []]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $confdata = array(
            'param' => 'dhcp_start_ip',
            'value' => $this->request->data['dhcp_start_ip']
            );

        $host_name_data = array(
            'param' => 'host_name',
            'value' => $this->request->data['host_name']
            );

        // 1ere methode de validation
        $dataconfig = $this->Config->patchEntity($dhcp_start_ip, $confdata, [
            'validate' => 'ipaddr',
            ]);
        $this->Config->save($dataconfig);

        $dataconfig = $this->Config->patchEntity($host_name, $host_name_data, [
            'validate' => 'name',
            ]);
        $this->Config->save($dataconfig);
    }
    $this->set('dhcp_start_ip', $dhcp_start_ip);
    $this->set('host_name', $host_name);
}
```

Model :

```
public function validationIpaddr(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator->notEmpty('value')
              ->add('value', 'notEmpty', [
                    'rule' => ['ip', 'ipv4'],
                    'message' => __('Invalid IP Address')
            ]);
    return $validator;
}

public function validationName(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
            ->add('value', 'notEmpty', [
                    'rule' => ['alphaNumeric'],
                    'message' => __('Invalid Name')
            ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, In your controller

```
$dataconfig = $this->Config->patchEntity($dhcp_start_ip, $confdata, [
  'validate' => 'ipaddr',
]);
if (!$dataconfig->errors()) {
  $this->Config->save($dataconfig);
}else{
  debug($dataconfig->errors());
  $this->Flash->error('Invalid IP Address!');
}
```